Laravel Routing Base URL includes extra stuff
I am new to Laravel Routing but I am trying to set up initial routes within my application. I have a route set up like this:
Route::get('/coach/base/athletes-dash', fn () => view('base::athletes-dash.index')) ->name('athletes.dash')

I have a pre-existing nav bar that I am trying to include this athletes dash in by:
:url="route('athletes.dash')"

However, my problem is that if I am on a page like localhost:8080/app-admin/admin.php?page=some-other-page then the link is to localhost:8080/app-admin/admin.php/coach/base/athletes-dash. I've tried other things like url('athletes.dash') with the same effect. The only thing that seems to work is explicitly writing the full url, localhost:8080/coach/base/athletes-dash, which would not translate to production. What am I doing wrong to reduce to the base url before adding in the rest?

do a artisan route:list

I see GET|HEAD coach/base/athletes-dash ..... athletes.dash. Not sure what else I should be looking for there

does restarting the server change anything?

Didn't seem to. I have also pushed to my staging server a couple times and see the same behavior there

php artisan route:list --name=athletes.dash does it return the route?

Yes, it returns the same as above, GET|HEAD coach/base/athletes-dash ..... athletes.dash

APP_URL in env? What do you use for frontend?
